# How can i create php hash array from another php array?

Tags: php, arrays, hash

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Poll] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [question] => What's your favourite linux distribution ?
                    [mark] => 1
                    [created] => 2011-09-05 20:30:57
                    [modified] => 2011-09-05 20:30:57
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Poll] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [question] => What's your favourite editor ?
                    [mark] => 1
                    [created] => 2011-09-05 20:31:59
                    [modified] => 2011-09-05 20:31:59
                )

        )

)
```

I want to get the array like this =>

```
            [Poll] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [question] => What's your favourite linux distribution ?
                    [mark] => 1
                    [created] => 2011-09-05 20:30:57
                    [modified] => 2011-09-05 20:30:57
                )
            [Poll] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [question] => What's your favourite editor ?
                    [mark] => 1
                    [created] => 2011-09-05 20:31:59
                    [modified] => 2011-09-05 20:31:59
                )
```

Is there any php function to do this or any shortcut way ?
I know about foreach loop.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the keys in a php array must be unique. Therefore, you cannot have `array("Poll"=>array(), "Poll"=>array());`. However, you can use the following

```
$r = array_map(function($subArray) {
  return $subArray['Poll'];
}, $inputArray);
```

This will make `$r` an array like this:

```
array(
  array(
    "id" => 1,
    "question" => "What's your favourite linux distribution ?",
    "mark" => 1,
    "created" => "2011-09-05 20:30:57",
    "modified" => "2011-09-05 20:30:57",
  ),
  array(
    "id" => 2,
    "question" => "What's your favourite editor ?",
    "mark" => 1,
    "created" => "2011-09-05 20:31:59",
    "modified" => "2011-09-05 20:31:59"
  )
);
```

You'd use it like this:

```
foreach($r as $qar) {
  echo $qar['question'] . ' (Created ' . $qar['created'] . ')';
}
```

By the way, you shouldn't store times in a textual format, and especially not in one without a timezone specification. Instead, use a UNIX timestamp as returned by [`time`](http://php.net/time) and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime), or a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object.

Comment: Now how would i access/get the value of 'question' ?